# Change "Garbage Icon" in shopping cart?

Tags: shopping-cart

How can I change the little garbage icon in my shopping cart? It's the one that removes the items from shopping cart? Mine is too small and one can hardly see what it is. Thanks

Comment: Which version of magento you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Magento 1.x** then you can find a image under

**skin\frontend\your theme\default\images**

if you have not customized it then image name will be something like

**icon_sprite.png** or **icon_sprite@2x.png**